# Storyboard - container view - embed different views based on condition

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In my storyboard app I have view hierarchy like this:

1. ParentViewController has a container view (dragged and dropped the container view from library on to the view of parent view controller).

**2. Container view can embed one of the three view controllers, based on some condition.**

While implementing second point I am facing problem.

If I try to do it in storyboard by control dragging from container view to a view controller, I can select viewDidLoad - embed segue. This will automatically embed the destination view controller, but then I will have no option to embed other view controllers based on some condition, say on tap of a different button.

Can anyone suggest me how can I implement the 2nd point?

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution: you can have three containers, each with it's own segue to another View Controller. Show one container and hide another two.

Comment: It is not a bad practice if you switch often between tree containers. But yes it is a bad practice in this case.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a bad practice, in fact it can be really usefull in some cases